# É uma prática ruim preencher <select> <option></option> com dados vindos do banco de dados?

Tags: html, sql, banco-de-dados, html-select

Seria uma má prática usar `selects` do HTML com itens obtidos através de um  banco de dados, mesmo eles sendo dinâmicos (sempre ocorrendo adição na tabela que os contêm).

Exemplo sem banco de dados:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">item 1</option>
  <option value="2">item 1</option>
  <option value="3">item 1</option>
```

Exemplo com banco de dados:

```
<select>
<?PHP foreach($dadosbanco as $value): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $value['item']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Só para dar um subsídio pra minha resposta, você imagina algum problema que possa ocorrer fazendo isso? Alguém disse que é ruim?

Comment: Em outro Post comentei sobre usar um método estático para fazer isso e recebi respostas não recomendando ai queria saber o motivo. Pq a meu ver isso facilitaria muito o trabalho tipo tem uma tabela órgão que sempre tem um novo e várias telas do sistema usa esse select ai de forma manual sempre vou no HTML e adiciono em cada tela e assim não precisaria mais.

Comment: Agora está melhorando, você pode [edit] a pergunta postando um *link* referenciando essa resposta.

Comment: @bigown depois do comentário ainda fiquei mais confuso... Thailes você quer saber se é má pratica fazer de modo estático ou de modo dinâmico?

Comment: @Jorge B. O método estático séria da classe a invocar o mesmo para executar o select dinâmico.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel faça [edit] na sua pergunta e adicione essa informação e se possível ponha o exemplo desse seu código.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel não entendi...

Comment: @bigown obrigado pela edição talvez agora ficou claro o objetivo. O motivo das negativações foi pq ela n ficou clara?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe esse negócio de "má prática". Existe o que precisa ser feito para resolver um problema, atender um requisito e fazer coisas gratuitas. Existe o fazer certo no caso concreto ou não. Eu percebo uma certa obsessão por "boas e más práticas" por quem ainda está começando, provavelmente incentivado por programadores mais experientes que querem "impor" seus gostos e não mostrar os fundamentos. As pessoas vão programar melhor quando elas entenderem que receitas prontas podem até ajudar, mas aplicadas sem entendimento mais atrapalham.

Então pergunte-se: consegue ver algum problema nisso? Esse problema ocorre em qualquer situação? Tem algo simples de contorná-lo? Existe alternativa mais viável? Há problemas de segurança, de performance, de manutenção? Preciso disto?

Se precisa pegar as opções do banco de dados e montar o HTML com as opções, deve fazer, não tem nenhuma razão para não fazer. Precisa fazer certo, claro. Se não precisa pegar do banco de dados, não tem porque fazê-lo. Essa é a pergunta que deve ser feita.

No exemplo mostrado na pergunta parece tudo certo (claro que precisaria ver se o resto do código está correto, mas esse trecho tudo certo), eu faria assim, supondo um cenário que isso seja útil. Pelas informações postadas do que vai usar parece precisar pegar do banco de dados.

Answer (score 4):

Não é viável determinar se há má prática no código apresentado.

A pergunta é vaga e cria um sentido desconexo.

Algo mais próximo de “má prática” pode ser o estilo usado na sintaxe PHP.

ex:

```
foreach($dadosbanco as $value):

endforeach
```

poderia ser

```
foreach ($dadosbanco as $value) {

}
```

Eu acredito que esse estilo é mais legível. Prefiro evitar formas alternativas. Pois apenas torna o código mais complexo, principalmente para novatos na linguagem. Mas é opinião pessoal e pode ignorar. Só não pode ignorar que existem padrões definidos e aceitos pela comunidade PHP np mundo inteiro. Atualmente há um esforço para difundir os "PSRs". Veja site oficial: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Apenas não confunda isso como se fosse uma lei, pois ninguém é obrigado a usar os padrões sugeridos por esse site e tampouco devemos julgar o estilo e padrões de códigos alheios comparando com os "PSRs".

Outro ponto é invocar `echo` num laço de repetição. Normalmente é mais lento do que ir concatenando e dar apenas um `echo`. Mas isso nem é muito relevante e tampouco considerado má prática.

Algo que imagino que pode chegar próximo ao objetivo da pergunta é que talvez você tenha ouvido falar algo sobre evitar misturar códigos HTML, PHP, etc. O tal do MVC.

Ainda assim, da forma como apresentou não há nenhuma má prática relevante.

Answer (score 3):

Não, não é uma má prática. Isso é usado a todo momento quando precisamos de opções de um select que são voláteis e estão armazenadas em banco. Como o pessoal acima já disse, muita coisa do que falam não ser uma boa prática na verdade é só um preciosismo. É claro que há um limite, mas neste caso não vejo problema algum.